# You need to have Ruby and Sass installed and in your PATH for this task to work

Tags: ruby, terminal, sass, gruntjs, local

I have ruby and sass installed but when I try to run the command below I get an error.

```
$ grunt sass
Running "sass:dist" (sass) task
Warning:
You need to have Ruby and Sass installed and in your PATH for this task to work.
More info: https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-sass
 Use --force to continue.
```

Aborted due to warnings.

I have tried reinstalling but im completely unsure how to fix this issue

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin sass
```